# Not displaying in div when array object is undefined

Tags: javascript, json

I'm grabbing some JSON with an array in it and displaying some of the data in an unordered list. The problem is that in some of the entries, the values I'm looking for aren't listed ("aristName" and "trackName"). So they return `undefined`. Based on what I have below, how would I omit each entry that returns an undefined value for "artistName" and "trackName," and only list the entries that do have those values?

```
var output="<ul>";

for (var i in data.onNow.playlist) {
    output+="<li>"+data.onNow.playlist[i].artistName+
        " - "+data.onNow.playlist[i].trackName+"</li>";
}

output+="</ul>";

document.getElementById("playlist-container").innerHTML=output;
```

Comment: You can use an `if` statement and test whether `artistName` or `trackName` are `undefined`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/if...else. To learn about the basic languages constructs, I recommend to read a tutorial (http://eloquentjavascript.net/, https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var output="<ul>";

for (var i in data.onNow.playlist) {
    var item = data.onNow.playlist[i];

    if (item.artistName && item.trackName) {
        output += "<li>" + item.artistName + " - " +
            item.trackName + "</li>";
    }
}

output += "</ul>";
```

That way you also filter out tracks and artists whose names are empty strings.

`if (foo)` evaluates to `false` when `foo` is an explicit `false`, `null`, `undefined`, the number `0`, an empty string or `NaN`. Otherwise it evaluates to true.